# algorithm2e - How to remove space between colon and text?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, algorithms, algorithm2e, pseudocode

How can I reduce this large space between colon and text in line with **Input:** ?
Also please how to remove align of text after **Input:** and **Precondition:** ? I am using `algorithm2e`. Is it possible with this package? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetAlgorithmName{Algorithm}{}{}
        \SetKwInOut{Precondition}{Precondition~}
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input~}
        \Input{~There is some fancy input definition.}
        \Precondition {~There is some fancy precondition.}
        \begin{doublespace}
            \eIf{$b=0$}
            {
                return $a$
            }
            {
                $b$
            }
        \end{doublespace}   
        \caption{Best algorithm ever.}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This is **actual** state:

[image]

This is **wanted** final state:

[image]

Comment: Your example, apart from not being complete, also does not compile

Comment: @Moriambar Sorry for that, should be ok now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `SetKwInput` for the first conditions, as `SetKwInOut` works just adjusting the space as you have seen.

Here an example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetAlgorithmName{Algorithm}{}{}
              \SetKwInput{Precondition}{Precondition~}
                              \SetKwInput{Input}{Input~}


        \Input{~There is some fancy input definition.}
        \Precondition {~There is some fancy precondition.}
        \begin{doublespace}
            \eIf{$b=0$}
            {
                return $a$
            }
            {
                $b$
            }
        \end{doublespace}   
        \caption{Best algorithm ever.}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

result:

[image]